# Using Delphi, unable to use anonymus type as a type of a record?

Tags: delphi, anonymous-methods

I don't understand why the following small console application does not compile:

```
program Project1;

type
  TProc = reference to procedure;

  TMyRec = record
    Proc: TProc;
  end;

var
  myProc: TProc;
  myRec: TMyRec;

begin
  myProc := procedure begin writeln; end;
  myProc; // compiles fine
  myRec.Proc := procedure begin writeln; end;
  myRec.Proc; //E2014 Statement exptected, but expression of type 'TProc' found
end.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must add parenthesis to indicate that you're calling the procedure; i.e.,

```
myRec.Proc();
```

Comment: Plain old pascal procedures can be invoked without parenthesis, I guess a Procedure-ref is different.

Comment: Thanks, I was not expecting this. What could be the reason for this requirement? How much this is different than from the myProc; line?

Comment: @WarrenP: IIRC this used to be the case with class method references as well, at least when you passed them into some other function as an argument...

Comment: Moreover, parens requirement is against Pascal standard.

Comment: @Marjan Passing arguments (more generally if `Proc;` or `Proc();` stand on the right side of assignment operator) is different - in this case `Proc;` and `Proc()`; have different meaning - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788424/anonymous-method-as-function-result/2788671#2788671